# Omit indices from a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am modifying a javascript object by altering a few things.
When I recreate it, I get an index number for each key pair.

```
"0":{...},"1":{...},
```

How do I remove/omit the creation of these 0,1,2,3,4 numbers? so that the output just looks:

```
{...},{...},
```

```js
var overlappedRanges = [{
  start: '11/19/2019',
  end: '11/20/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/01/2019',
  end: '11/18/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/14/2019',
  end: '11/19/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/17/2019',
  end: '11/21/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/12/2019',
  end: '11/23/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/18/2019',
  end: '11/24/2019'
}];


var final = {};
for (var key in overlappedRanges){
final[key] = {"startmod" : overlappedRanges[key]["start"],
"endmod" : overlappedRanges[key]["end"]};
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(final));



$('#overlapped').text(JSON.stringify(final));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="overlapped" style="color: red;"></span>
<br>
<span id="notOverlapped" style="color: green;"></span>
```

Comment: you can't - because `{...},{...}` is not valid JSON - you could simply JSON.stringify the original Array - then you won't get the keys ... you'll get `[{...},{...}]`

Comment: Well, `overlappedRanges` is an array, not an object.  So when you do a `for..in` loop the key will be the index.  I'm not sure what you are expected `key` to me.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the numeric indexes from the array as keys in the `final` object. A simpler way to recreate the objects would be to use `Array.map()` to iterate the array:

```js
var overlappedRanges = [{"start":"11/19/2019","end":"11/20/2019"},{"start":"11/01/2019","end":"11/18/2019"},{"start":"11/14/2019","end":"11/19/2019"},{"start":"11/17/2019","end":"11/21/2019"},{"start":"11/12/2019","end":"11/23/2019"},{"start":"11/18/2019","end":"11/24/2019"}];

var final = overlappedRanges.map(({ start: startmod, end: endmod }) => ({ 
  startmod, endmod 
}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(final));
```

For browsers that don't support ES6, you'll need to replace the arrow function with a function that has a return statment, and create the object with standard assignment:

```js
var overlappedRanges = [{"start":"11/19/2019","end":"11/20/2019"},{"start":"11/01/2019","end":"11/18/2019"},{"start":"11/14/2019","end":"11/19/2019"},{"start":"11/17/2019","end":"11/21/2019"},{"start":"11/12/2019","end":"11/23/2019"},{"start":"11/18/2019","end":"11/24/2019"}];

var final = overlappedRanges.map(function(o) {
  return { 
    startmod: o.start, 
    endmod: o.end 
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(final));
```

Comment: what would be the equivalent for IE 11 for this arrow function?

Comment: Use the brackets notation - `o['0']`.

Answer (score 1):

Have the outer structure be an array instead of an object:

```js
var overlappedRanges = [{
  start: '11/19/2019',
  end: '11/20/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/01/2019',
  end: '11/18/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/14/2019',
  end: '11/19/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/17/2019',
  end: '11/21/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/12/2019',
  end: '11/23/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/18/2019',
  end: '11/24/2019'
}];

const final = overlappedRanges.map(({ start, end }) => ({
  startmod: start,
  endmod: end
}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(final));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="overlapped" style="color: red;"></span>
<br>
<span id="notOverlapped" style="color: green;"></span>
```

(Also, use `.map` to transform one array into another)